# Cannot compile with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex

I was using XeLaTeX do compile all my documents. But, yesterday I formatted my laptop to Windows 10, and I installed TexLive agian. But, now when I try to compile my existing documents, that used to be compiled, I just cannot.

I get the errors that can be seen below. Plus it is no longer recognizing Computer Modern font. Isn't it the default Latex font? Please note that I'm using TexMaker.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Here is also my full .tex file.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

% Language
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
% Context sensitive quotation
\usepackage{csquotes}
% Citations
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{References.bib}
% Custom enumerations
\usepackage{enumerate}
% Extend options for positioning floats
\usepackage{float}
% Support highlighting of certain parts of the text
\usepackage{framed}
% Definitions for mathematical type setting
\usepackage{mathtools}
% Headers & Footers
\usepackage[automark, nouppercase]{scrpage2}
% To change the format of titles
\usepackage{titlesec}
% Support for unicode math fonts
\usepackage{unicode-math}
% Extended color support
\usepackage{xcolor}
% Extras for XƎTEX
\usepackage{xltxtra}
% Hyperlinks and pdf properties
\usepackage{hyperref}
% TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,hobby,backgrounds,calc,trees, fit, shapes.geometric}


\newcommand{\Title}{}
\newcommand{\TitleDescription}{}
\newcommand{\Version}{1}
\newcommand{\Subject}{}
\newcommand{\KeyWords}{}
\newcommand{\LeftFooter}{}

\newcommand{\AuthorOne}{}
\newcommand{\MailOne}{\href{mailto:}{}}

% Highlight and tab some text
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.1\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}

% Syntax highlighting definitions
\newcommand{\hlstd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.49,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlesc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlstr}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.75,0.01,0.01}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlpps}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.51,0.51,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlslc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.51,0.51,0.51}{\it{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.51,0.51,0.51}{\it{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlppc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0.51,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlopt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hllin}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.33,0.33,0.33}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlkwa}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\bf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlkwb}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0.34,0.68}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlkwc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\bf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlkwd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0.51}{#1}}

% Background color for syntax highlighting
\definecolor{bgcolor}{rgb}      {1,     1,      1}

% Custom color definitions
\definecolor{aqua}{rgb}         {0,     0.56,   1}
\definecolor{bluegray}{rgb}     {0.22,  0.46,   0.84}
\definecolor{grape}{rgb}        {0.56,  0,      1}
\definecolor{orchid}{rgb}       {0.41,  0.13,   0.55}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}       {1,     0.54,   0}
\definecolor{silver}{rgb}       {0.57,  0.57,   0.57}
\definecolor{turquoise}{rgb}    {0,     0.86,   0.84}

% No indendation after paragraph
\setlength\parindent{0cm}

% Hyperref properties
\hypersetup
{
    pdftitle    = {\Title},
    pdfsubject  = {\Subject},
    pdfauthor   = {\AuthorOne},
    pdfkeywords = {\KeyWords},
    colorlinks  = true,
    linkcolor   = black,
    anchorcolor = black,
    citecolor   = silver,
    urlcolor    = black
}

% Use same size for numbers and other text
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}

% Define font styles
\newfontfamily\Zapfino{Computer Modern}

% Use normal font instead of italic font for head
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont}

% Set headers and footers
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{}
\ifoot{\LeftFooter}
\ofoot{\thepage}

% Set height of head
\setlength{\headheight}{1.8\baselineskip}

% Set thickness of separation line in header, footer
\setheadsepline{0.5pt}
\setfootsepline{0.5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

    \begin{center}
        % Title and title-description
        {\Huge\Zapfino \Title}
        \vskip 0.5cm
        {\Large\textit\TitleDescription}
        \vskip 1cm
        \hrule
        \vskip 0.5cm
        % Information about author
        \begin{tabular}{p{8cm}l}
            \AuthorOne  & \MailOne\\
        \end{tabular}
        \vskip 0.5cm
        \hrule
        \vskip 13.5cm
    \end{center}

    % Date and version number
    \begin{leftbar}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \textbf{Version}    & \Version\\
            \textbf{Date}       & \today
        \end{tabular}
    \end{leftbar}

\end{titlepage}

% Modify space before and after a chapter
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{10pt}
% Set chapter format for table of contents
\titleformat{\chapter}{\sffamily\bfseries\large}{}{0pt}{}[{\color{aqua}\hrule}]

% Set separation of dots between name of section and page number to such a high
% value that there will be no points in the table of contents
\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000} \makeatother
% Use blank header and footer
\pagestyle{empty}
% Suppress page number
\pagenumbering{gobble}
% Start on new page
\newpage
% The table of contents starts at the second page
\setcounter{page}{2}

% Set table of contents
%\tableofcontents
% Suppress page number
\thispagestyle{empty}

\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\Large\sffamily\bfseries}  % Bold, large, sans serif font for section
    {}                          % No format applied to whole title
    {0pt}                       % No separation between label and title
    {\thechapter ~•~ }          % Start with chapter number
    % Underline with blue ruler, Use default style for headers, footers
    [{\color{aqua}\hrule}\thispagestyle{scrheadings}]

% Set format for other sections and paragraphs
% Color = orchid, Font = bold, sans serif
\titleformat*{\section}{\color{black}\sffamily\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\color{black}\sffamily\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\color{black}\sffamily\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\color{black}\sffamily\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\color{black}\sffamily\bfseries}

% Start with text on a new page
\newpage
% Display headers and footers
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
% Restore arabic page numbering
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newpage\chapter{2}

\section{ML2}

\paragraph{Solution:} 

\begin{enumerate}
\item $\Box (A \supset A)$.
\end{enumerate}

\newpage
% Suppress page number
\pagenumbering{gobble}
% Set section format for bibliography
\titleformat{\chapter}{\sffamily\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[{\color{aqua}\hrule}]
% Display bibliography
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Any ideas what the problem might be, and how to solve it?

Comment: You will need to update your expl3 packages as well, error is probably related to this.

Comment: I've no problem compiling this code.

Comment: Did everything run smoothly with the texlive installation?  What happens if you run pdflatex on a simpler document?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides What's the process of updating a single package, like in this case, expl3? I have never done it before.

Comment: @jarauh I assume everything ran smoothly. I didn't see any error messages. And yes I can compile a simple document using pdflatex.

Comment: @Bernard Well, apparently I get the above mentioned problems, and it also doesn't recognize the Computer Modern font, so I had to change it.

Comment: The default with `fontspec` and `xelatex` is `Latin Modern`.

Comment: @Bernard Ok thanks for that info. But, still I cannot compile it due to the first error.

Comment: @modpro: I've just posted a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

`\Box` is not defined in basic latex. You have to load `latexsym` for that (compatible with `unicode-math`, it seems).

The other problem is the last version of the `hobby` library package. You can either not load it, or use a fix that you can download from [github](https://github.com/loopspace/hobby).

For the last solution, described as ‘quite possibly not a good fix’, you have to pdflatex hobby.dtx, and install the resulting `hobby.code.tex, pgflibraryhobby.code.tex, tikzlibraryhobby.code.tex` and `pml3array.sty` in `…\latex\hobby\`, either in `texmf-local` or your personal texmf directory. You'll remove it when an official fix will be available.

Comment: How can I now load `hobby`? I mean this is a template that I use, meaning it was written by someone else, and I don't know exactly which part is using `hobby`.

Comment: You don't have to load it: it's loaded by this line of your template: `\usetikzlibrary{arrows, hobby, backgrounds,calc,trees, fit, shapes.geometric}%`. All you have to do is to install the fix as I explained.